# How to stop Visual Studio 2008 collapsing white space between operands and operator?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

For example I like to keep my right hand operands left aligned in the same col:

```
int a                       = 1;
string aLongVaribleName     = "test";
```

But if I touch the code such as adding the ';' at the end VS collapses it to:

```
int a = 1;
string aLongVaribleName = "test";
```

Is there any option to stop VS doing this?

Comment: Type Ctrl+Z.  That undoes the formatting, not the ;

Comment: I know - its still a pain everytime - and not only modifying a line or adding semi-colon does it - so does adding the closing brace } which does it to the whole block!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tools > Options > TextEditor > C# > Formatting
```

[image: options dialog]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools > Options...Then go to Text Editor > C# > Formatting > General.  There are 3 auto format options there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a VB macro for VS03/05, should be good for 08 also: http://omegacoder.com/?p=8

Bit off topic, as for VS2010, you can use either:

Productivity PowerToy: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/view/Reviews/12

OR

NoahRic's AlignAssignment: https://github.com/noahric/AlignAssignments